# Javascript loop infinitely up till a certain condition

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, infinite-loop

```
// Contains a list of items in each set.
var sets[0] = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
    sets[1] = [10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18],
    sets[2] = [19,20,21,22,23,25,26,27]

// Contains the mins associated to each set item.
var setTimes[0] = [15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15],
    setTimes[1] = [16,12,11,15,13,15,15,15,14],
    setTimes[2] = [16,12,11,15,13,12,11,15,13]
```

I've got a set of arrays as given above. The sets array has a data set of values. This array can have n number of items in it. Ex, `sets[n]`.
Each `sets` array has an equivalent `setTimes` array that has minutes stored in it. `setTimes[0][0]` is 15min and is the number of minutes for `sets[0][0]`.

Given a set item(ex 12), I'd like to:

1. Find out which set array does the given number belong to? In our case, since 12 was the item, it belongs to `sets[1]`.
2. Once I have this, I'd like to get the sum of all mins from the `setTimes` array for the current sets index and also the next index. In our case, that would be the sum of `setTimes[1]` and `setTimes[2]`.
3. In the event we reach the end of sets array, I'd like to get the sum of the first set array.
   For ex, 
       - if I pass 12, I'll need to get the sum of `setTimes[1]` and `setTimes[2]`
       - If I pass 23, I'll need to get the sum of `setTimes[2]` and `setTimes[0]`

Here is the loop I've been thinking, would like to know if there is a better way of doing this.

```
function computeTotalMin(givenItem)
{
    // represents how many sets to loop thorough. I need 2.
    for (x = 0; x <= 1; x++)
    {
        for(i = 0; i < sets.length; i++)
        {
            // checking to see if i value is on the last index of the sets array.
            if(i === sets.length - 1)
            {
                i = 0;
                var item = sets[i].indexOf(givenItem);

                if(item !== -1)
                {
                    // Loops through all mins from setTimes[i] array
                    for(j = 0; j < setTimes[i].length; j++)
                    {
                        var total = total + setTimes[j];
                    }
                }
            }

        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: What does this question have to do with an infinite loop?

Comment: This question may be better suited for Code Review.

Comment: Do you want to call computeTotalMin recursively?

Comment: @Bergi: I might have used the wrong terminology. I'd like to keep looping over the sets array n number of times. And if during the loop, should it reach the end, i'd like to start over from the first set.

Comment: @Blauharley: Its not recursive, it just loops over a given array n times where n is changeable. The code ive pasted, i suspect will go through an infinite loop, since i'm reseting the i value to 0 once i reaches the last index of sets. This might cause the i loop to keep going on infinitely. Was wondering if my approach is correct or is there a better way to accomplish this.

Comment: @user3771837: you're looking for the [`continue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/continue) (or `break`) statements. The outer loop is just a normal, finite `0`->`n-1` iteration.

Comment: @Bergi: I'm not sure if a continue or break might be useful here as once the end is reached, i cant just break out of the loop as i've got to take the next possible sequence. Ex: if i start at index 1, ill need to go through index 1 and 2. But if i start at index 2, i'll need to go over index 2 and then index 0. I might be missing something?

Comment: Oops forget what I said. I've understood your question now, will write an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need two nested loops for continuing at the end. You should have a single loop that iterates the number of sets you're interested in (2), and has an index (starting at the one set you've found). Inside that loop, you'd make a modulo operation on the index; to get back to the start when you've reached the end. By only looping over the count, not the (resettable) index, you won't get into an infinite loop.

You also should divide your program in just those tasks that you've textually described (find this, then do that), instead of munching everything in one huge nested control structure.

```
function computeTotalMin(givenItem) {
    var setIndex = -1;
    for (; setIndex < sets.length; setIndex++)
        if (sets[setIndex].indexOf(givenItem) > -1)
            break;
    if (setIndex == sets.length)
        return null; // givenItem found in none of the sets

    var sum = 0;
    for (var count = 0; count < 2; count++) {
        for (var i=0; i<setTimes[setIndex].length; i++)
            sum += setTimes[setIndex][i];

        setIndex++; // go to next set
        setIndex %= sets.length; // which might be 0
        // alternatively: if (setIndex == sets.length) setIndex = 0;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: Let me know if i understood what you said. Remove the top level loop and have a counter var storing how many times i need the loop to run. Then a simple if condition to check if i === sets.length - 1, total = sum(setTimes[i]) + sum(setTimes[i%n]), else total = sum(setTimes[i]) + sum(setTimes[i+1])?

Comment: Also, thx for the suggestion for the code clean up. Was just trying to get the logic to work and then will separate them into individual tasks doing just that one thing.

Comment: No, you shouldn't hard-code those two runs like `setTimes[i]) + sum(setTimes[(i+1)%n])`, or even make an explicit condition for whether you need to wrap around or not *for* these *two* runs. Instead, use a loop for this (going on the number of runs), and make the wrap-around of the index dynamic in each iteration.

Comment: This is basically having two variables (the count of the runs, and the index for the array) running in the same, *one* loop. You'll need to "merge" your two top-most loops into a single one. In the code in your question, the `i=0` assignment will indeed make the inner loop infinite.

Comment: I hope the code I've amended can clarify what I meant.